# Disable UIControl for some duration

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can i disable a button for a short duration? I have a sign up view, on 3 wrong attempts it will take user outside signup view and it will disable signup button for some time say 5 minutes. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- (void) processAfterWrongAttempts {
    button.enabled = NO;

    double delayInSeconds = 5.0 * 60;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds *   NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        button.enabled = YES;
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, the best approach..dude I was writing down the same answer. :P

Comment: @Gihan No other threads were used. A block will be executed on the main thread. Blocks are lightweight.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is use Grand Central Dispatch. GCD is your friend.

The way it works is you will request a certain block of code to be executed after a certain time.

Let's assume `myButton` is a button you want to disable and then only enable after a certain time, and `numTries` is the amount of times you've tried to signing up:

in your header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int numTries;
```

in your implementation (.m) file:

```
@synthesize numTries = numTries_;


- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    self.numTries++;
    if (self.numTries > 3) {
        myButton.enabled = NO;
        double delayInSeconds = 15.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            myButton.enabled = YES;
            numTries = 0;
        });
    }
}
```

This will result in that block of code being executed after 15 seconds. You can of course change `delayInSeconds` to whatever value you wish. `dispatch_get_main_queue()` returns the UI thread, meaning that the code in the block `^{ ... }` executes on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Blaine Murray :) It works fine

Answer (score 1):

Disable Signup Button then, 
Schedule `NSTimer` for 5 min.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300.0f target:self selector:@selector(showSignUpButton:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)showSignUpButton:(NSTimer *)timer
{ 
    [signUpButton setEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can disable button when you want. After it, you can call timer for 5 min. and when timer will fire. you can enable that button..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this

```
- (void) startTimer {
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                                    target:self 
                                  selector:@selector(enable) 
                                  userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:NO];
}

- (void) enable {
   [signUpButton setEnabled:YES];

}
```

Better solution would be to use performSelector instead of scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval

```
 [self performSelector:@select(enable) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Disable button at start
[self performSelector:@select(showButton) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
//write enable button code in showButton method
```

other way around is

```
[self performBlock:^{ 
  //enable button
  } afterDelay:5.0f];
```